# Cannot add a WFE to the farm

Tags: 2010

When trying to add a new WFE server to the farm. I get the following error.

```
Connect-SPConfigurationDatabase : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: service
At C:\Users\svcIMSSP2010Setup\Desktop\JoinServertoSPFarm.ps1:35 char:32
+ Connect-SPConfigurationDatabase <<<<  -DatabaseServer $DBServer -DatabaseName
 $DBName -Passphrase (ConvertTo-SecureString $PassPhrase -AsPlainText -Force )
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...urationDatabase:
   SPCmdletConnectSPConfigurationDatabase) [Connect-SPConfigurationDatabase],
   ArgumentNullException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletConnectS
   PConfigurationDatabase
```

This when running the command

```
Connect-SPConfigurationDatabase -DatabaseServer $DBServer -DatabaseName $DBName -Passphrase (ConvertTo-SecureString $PassPhrase -AsPlainText -Force )
```

Comment: If you output $DBServer, $DBName, $PassPhrase, are they outputting what you expect?

Comment: Yes. The parameter are correct.